# Return Success on NodeJS + AJAX&XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, node.js

when I try to return success, I always receive an error.

Here is my script code:

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function(){
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        //Upload progress
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
            console.log('up');
            uploadProgress(evt);
        }, false);
        //Download progress
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
            console.log('down');
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    url : 'upload',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'xml',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (result) {
        alert('success!');
    },
    error: function(err){
        alert("error --'");
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

And I try to return the success message with this:

```
var response = {
    status  : 200,
    success : 'Updated Successfully'
}
res.type('json');
res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
```

or this:

```
res.end('{"success" : "Updated Successfully", "status" : 200}');
```

or this:

```
res.status(200).send(JSON.parse('{"success":"Hey"}'));
```

e.t.c ...

And I always have an error alert. . .

Comment: Why not return `res.json({key: value})`? And in fact you're setting an incorrect response type. It should be `application\json`

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin do you mean something like this? `res.status(200).type('application/json').json({success:'Hello'});`
Because it's not works :X

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin , same result....

Comment: Could you please post your node configurations?
Simply, you can write `res.send({ key: value});` with `application/json` as `content-type` like this `res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');`

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin here is the solution: `res.status(200).type('text/xml').send(xml({success:'Hello'}))` not the same, but thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

> If you want to send **xml** data, you need to send response with the same type :)

Changes:

```
var xml = require('xml');
//and response:
res.status(200).type('text/xml').send(xml({success:'Hello'}));
```

Comment: You were getting an error because the front end is expecting xml in the response (see the `dataType` option in your $.ajax function), and you are returning json from the back end. Glad you were able to figure it out. Feel free to accept your own answer so this issue can be marked as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `url: 'upload'` on the options passed to ajax is right?
Also, on the error handler try this:

```
 error: (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert("error --'");
        console.log(jqXHR.status);
    }
```

Then see if you are getting an HTTP 404, or maybe a 500 which means the actual server is hitted but there is an error in the backend

If you're getting a 200 back, then your issue should be a malformed json returned from the server, try this instead when returning the json:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.end(JSON.stringify(object));
```

Comment: @IvanDunets That doesnt make any sense, 200 status means there was no error, so the success callback should have been called, unless the json data returned from the server is malformed

Comment: maybe....
That is my res. : `res.status(200).type('application/json').json({success:'Hello'})`

Comment: An hour ago I tried the same, but this does not work, as incredible as it may seem

Comment: Incorrect type dude :) `text/xml` And thanks for help ;)